# JSON not getting passed to controller via JQuery

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I can't seem to get the json (verified valid) to the `UpdateCaps` controller from ListBox:

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult UpdateCaps(List<SelectListItem> selectedItems)
{
    var test = selectedItems;
    return Json(test);
}
```

**ListBox:**

```
   @(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
        .Name("selected")
        .ConnectWith("optional")
        .Selectable(ListBoxSelectable.Multiple)
        .DropSources("optional")
        .DataTextField("Description")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .Toolbar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Position(ListBoxToolbarPosition.Right);
        })
        .DataSource(source => source
            .Custom()
            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
            .Transport(transport => transport
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetSelectedCapsUnits", "OrgStructure").Data("level1Select"))
            )
        )
        .Events(events => events
            .Add("onAdd")
            .Remove("onRemove")
        )
        .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>())
    )
```

**The `onAdd` in the listbox triggers this javascript:**

```
function onAdd(e) {
    console.log(e.dataItems);
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ selectedItems: e.dataItems }))
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/OrgStructure/UpdateCaps",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify({ selectedItems: e.dataItems }),
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
          alert("Successfully sent to server: " + result.map(function (x) {
                 return x.Text
             }))
         }
     });

    $('#selectedListBox').text(' ' + e.dataItems.length + " added - saved");  

}
```

**Verified the JSON string is valid:**
[image]
With: `console.log(JSON.stringify({ selectedItems: e.dataItems }))`

**It fires the `UpdateCaps` method `onAdd` but no results:**
[image]

Comment: I would try without the `JSON.stringify(...)`.  Essentially try sending the object, rather than a string representation of the object.

Comment: @DrewB. tried `data: e.dataItems,` but still `Count = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this line of code:

`JSON.stringify({ selectedItems: e.dataItems }),`

to

`JSON.stringify(e.dataItems),`

The problem is that you are sending back to the controller an object which contains a property named `selectedItems` which holds a list of objects. You have to pass the list instead.

Based on your comment, you do not need a `List<SelectListItem>` as parameter.

Create the following class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and update your code to expect a list of `MyModel`:

```
public IActionResult UpdateCaps([FromBody]List<MyModel> models)
```